# What is kernel Space and User space.

Tags: linux, kernel

what is Kernel space ? i want to understand it and same with User space
and what is the diff between them

Answer (score -1):

Kernel space is strictly reserved for running a privileged operating system kernel, kernel extensions, and most device drivers. In contrast, user space is the memory area where application software and some drivers execute. Reference link: http://rhelblog.redhat.com/2015/07/29/architecting-containers-part-1-user-space-vs-kernel-space/